# Selenium | To print by moving numbers from 1 to 22 using range (1,23)

Tags: selenium, for-loop, xpath, range, element

I want to print by moving numbers from 1 to 22 using range (1,23)
Can you help me?

````
number = 1
numf = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/main/section/ul/li[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[%d]/button' %number)
for i in numf:
    print(i.text)```
````

Comment: '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/main/section/ul/li[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li['+ str(number)+']/button' in a enumerate would do it,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `%s`:

  ```
  number = 1
  numf = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/main/section/ul/li[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[%s]/button"% str(number))
  ```
- Using `format()`:

  ```
  number = 1
  numf = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/main/section/ul/li[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[{}]/button".format(str(number)))
  ```

Comment: Can't i list one by one? 
I have to store a lot of data like 'data1', 'data2' this way.

Comment: @g0dst3r Of coarse you can. But shouldn't that be a different question all together? Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement please. StackOverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.